# How to create a cached recursive type?

Tags: recursion, types, f#

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type Node<'a>(expr:'a, symbol:int) = 
    member x.Expression = expr
    member x.Symbol = symbol
    override x.GetHashCode() = symbol
    override x.Equals(y) = 
        match y with 
        | :? Node<'a> as y -> symbol = y.Symbol
        | _ -> failwith "Invalid equality for Node."

    interface IComparable with
        member x.CompareTo(y) = 
            match y with
            | :? Node<'a> as y -> compare symbol y.Symbol
            | _ -> failwith "Invalid comparison for Node."

type Ty =
    | Int
    | String
    | Tuple of Ty list
    | Rec of Node<Ty>
    | Union of Ty list

type NodeDict<'a> = Dictionary<'a,Node<'a>>

let get_nodify_tag =
    let mutable i = 0
    fun () -> i <- i+1; i

let nodify (dict: NodeDict<_>) x =
    match dict.TryGetValue x with
    | true, x -> x
    | false, _ ->
        let x' = Node(x,get_nodify_tag())
        dict.[x] <- x'
        x'

let d = Dictionary(HashIdentity.Structural)
let nodify_ty x = nodify d x

let rec int_string_stream = 
    Union 
        [
        Tuple [Int; Rec (nodify_ty (int_string_stream))]
        Tuple [String; Rec (nodify_ty (int_string_stream))]
        ]
```

In the above example, the `int_string_stream` gives a type error, but it neatly illustrates what I want to do. Of course, I want both sides to get tagged with the same `symbol` in `nodify_ty`. When I tried changing the `Rec` type to `Node<Lazy<Ty>>` I've found that it does not compare them correctly and each sides gets a new symbol which is useless to me.

I am working on a language, and the way I've dealt with storing recursive types up to now is by mapping `Rec` to an `int` and then substituting that with the related `Ty` in a dictionary whenever I need it. Currently, I am in the process of cleaning up the language, and would like to have the `Rec` case be `Node<Ty>` rather than an `int`.

At this point though, I am not sure what else could I try here. Could this be done somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to add some form of explicit "delay" to the discriminated union that represents your types. Without an explicit delay, you'll always end up fully evaluating the types and so there is no potential for closing the loop.

Something like this seems to work:

```
type Ty =
    | Int
    | String
    | Tuple of Ty list
    | Rec of Node<Ty>
    | Union of Ty list
    | Delayed of Lazy<Ty>

// (rest is as before)

let rec int_string_stream = Delayed(Lazy.Create(fun () ->
    Union 
        [
        Tuple [Int; Rec (nodify_ty (int_string_stream))]
        Tuple [String; Rec (nodify_ty (int_string_stream))]
        ]))
```

This will mean that when you pattern match on `Ty`, you'll always need to check for `Delayed`, evaluate the lazy value and then pattern match again, but that's probably doable!

Comment: Yes, this will definitely make it doable. But when I was testing it with something like `Tuple [Int; Rec (nodify_ty (lazy int_string_stream))]` what happened was that each time I'd reevaluate the `int_string_stream` expressions, different nodes would be added into the dictionary. I am surprised that putting the `lazy` at the beginning makes a difference. Why is that?

Comment: In fact the more I think about it, the more I find it strange that it does not make new `Symbol`s on reevaluation (when I send just the `int_string_stream ` let binding into the REPL). If it is comparing based on reference equality in the dictionary, the behavior I would expect is that it would...

Comment: Er, it in fact does do that. I made a mistake during testing and got confused, now it all makes sense. Sorry about that. To answer my first question, the reason why writing `Rec (nodify_ty (lazy int_string_stream))` is bad rather than putting lazy at the beginning is that when I have `Tuple [Int; Rec (nodify_ty (lazy int_string_stream))]; Tuple [String; Rec (nodify_ty (lazy int_string_stream))]`, two different reference would get set to the dictionary. That is it. You are great on setting me on the right track.